# How to open up a matrix that's running into an error

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling

I am running into an error on a big job in R. I running it as an R script. I keep getting the error that `Error in chol.default(F.mat) :
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite`.

I normally run my job in a qsub but that only gives me an error output but I can't poke around. I then tried running my job locally but my 4gb Macbook was completely overwhelmed.

Now I am trying using `screen name` and running it on a screen with `options(error=recover)`. Now I am running into the same error as above but I don't know how to access the data frames. I get `recover called non-interactively; frames dumped, use debugger() to view` but then I get put into my bash line and I don't know how to open up the data frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could accept Ben's answer because it is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit awkward since (1) it's more or less remote debugging and (2) I don't actually ever try to debug non-interactively myself, but: it seems that
`options(error=function() dump.frames(to.file=TRUE))` might be worth trying?

After your frames dump to a file (`last.dump.rda` in the working directory,by default), you should be able to run `load("last.dump.rda"); debugger(last.dump)` to get back to the debugging environment.

Two caveats:

- I haven't actually tested this, just read & interpreted `?dump.frames`;
- I *strongly* recommend that you test this with short test runs, either running your original code on a small subset of your data or setting a mini-test script something like

```
 options(error=function() dump.frames(to.file=TRUE))
 Sys.sleep(60)
 stop("testing error exit")
```